# Header on LLNCS macro package for Springer Computer Science proceedings

Tags: header-footer

I am currently trying to edit the Header of my Thesis paper. which needs to be written with the LNCS sample paper template, while my Title consist of 16 words which leads to my header on odd pages showing "Title Suppressed Due to Excessive Length" as depicted in the screen shot below.

Is it possible to remove the "Title Suppressed" and just have the page number of this. I did try `\pagestyle{plain}` but this moves the page number to the footer.

[image: Page Header]

> ```
> \documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \usepackage{epstopdf}
> \usepackage[official]{eurosym}
> \usepackage{xcolor}
> \usepackage{tabularx, caption}
> \usepackage{multirow}
> \usepackage{t1enc}
> \usepackage{layaureo}
> \usepackage{multicol}
> \usepackage[ msc-links]{amsrefs}
> \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
> \usepackage{tikz}
> \usepackage{float}
> \usepackage{gensymb}
> \usepackage{amsrefs}
> \usepackage{python}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \usepackage{subcaption}
> \usepackage{mwe}
> ```

```
% Used for displaying a sample figure. If possible, figure files should
% be included in EPS format.
%
% If you use the hyperref package, please uncomment the following line
% to display URLs in blue roman font according to Springer's eBook style:
% \renewcommand\UrlFont{\color{blue}\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
%
\title{Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}
%
%\titlerunning{Abbreviated paper title}
% If the paper title is too long for the running head, you can set
% an abbreviated paper title here
%
\author{First Author\inst{1}\orcidID{0000-1111-2222-3333} \and
Second Author\inst{2,3}\orcidID{1111-2222-3333-4444} \and
Third Author\inst{3}\orcidID{2222--3333-4444-5555}}
%
\authorrunning{F. Author et al.}
% First names are abbreviated in the running head.
% If there are more than two authors, 'et al.' is used.
%
\institute{Princeton University, Princeton NJ 08544, USA \and
Springer Heidelberg, Tiergartenstr. 17, 69121 Heidelberg, Germany
\email{lncs@springer.com}\\
\url{http://www.springer.com/gp/computer-science/lncs} \and
ABC Institute, Rupert-Karls-University Heidelberg, Heidelberg, Germany\\
\email{\{abc,lncs\}@uni-heidelberg.de}}
%
\maketitle              % typeset the header of the contribution
%
\begin{abstract}
The abstract should briefly summarize the contents of the paper in
150--250 words.

\keywords{First keyword  \and Second keyword \and Another keyword.}
\end{abstract}
%
%
%
\section{First Section}
\subsection{A Subsection Sample}
Please note that the first paragraph of a section or subsection is
not indented. The first paragraph that follows a table, figure,
equation etc. does not need an indent, either.

Subsequent paragraphs, however, are indented.

\subsubsection{Sample Heading (Third Level)} Only two levels of
headings should be numbered. Lower level headings remain unnumbered;
they are formatted as run-in headings.

\paragraph{Sample Heading (Fourth Level)}
The contribution should contain no more than four levels of
headings. Table~\ref{tab1} gives a summary of all heading levels.

\begin{table}
\caption{Table captions should be placed above the
tables.}\label{tab1}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Heading level &  Example & Font size and style\\
\hline
Title (centered) &  {\Large\bfseries Lecture Notes} & 14 point, bold\\
1st-level heading &  {\large\bfseries 1 Introduction} & 12 point, bold\\
2nd-level heading & {\bfseries 2.1 Printing Area} & 10 point, bold\\
3rd-level heading & {\bfseries Run-in Heading in Bold.} Text follows & 10 point, bold\\
4th-level heading & {\itshape Lowest Level Heading.} Text follows & 10 point, italic\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\noindent Displayed equations are centered and set on a separate
line.
\begin{equation}
x + y = z
\end{equation}
Please try to avoid rasterized images for line-art diagrams and
schemas. Whenever possible, use vector graphics instead (see
Fig.~\ref{fig1}).

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1.eps}
\caption{A figure caption is always placed below the illustration.
Please note that short captions are centered, while long ones are
justified by the macro package automatically.} \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\begin{theorem}
This is a sample theorem. The run-in heading is set in bold, while
the following text appears in italics. Definitions, lemmas,
propositions, and corollaries are styled the same way.
\end{theorem}
%
% the environments 'definition', 'lemma', 'proposition', 'corollary',
% 'remark', and 'example' are defined in the LLNCS documentclass as well.
%
\begin{proof}
Proofs, examples, and remarks have the initial word in italics,
while the following text appears in normal font.
\end{proof}
For citations of references, we prefer the use of square brackets
and consecutive numbers. Citations using labels or the author/year
convention are also acceptable. The following bibliography provides
a sample reference list with entries for journal
articles~\cite{ref_article1}, an LNCS chapter~\cite{ref_lncs1}, a
book~\cite{ref_book1}, proceedings without editors~\cite{ref_proc1},
and a homepage~\cite{ref_url1}. Multiple citations are grouped
\cite{ref_article1,ref_lncs1,ref_book1},
\cite{ref_article1,ref_book1,ref_proc1,ref_url1}.

\newpage
This is a Testpage
%
% ---- Bibliography ----
%
% BibTeX users should specify bibliography style 'splncs04'.
% References will then be sorted and formatted in the correct style.
%
% \bibliographystyle{splncs04}
% \bibliography{mybibliography}
%
\begin{thebibliography}{8}
\bibitem{ref_article1}
Author, F.: Article title. Journal \textbf{2}(5), 99--110 (2016)

\bibitem{ref_lncs1}
Author, F., Author, S.: Title of a proceedings paper. In: Editor,
F., Editor, S. (eds.) CONFERENCE 2016, LNCS, vol. 9999, pp. 1--13.
Springer, Heidelberg (2016). \doi{10.10007/1234567890}

\bibitem{ref_book1}
Author, F., Author, S., Author, T.: Book title. 2nd edn. Publisher,
Location (1999)

\bibitem{ref_proc1}
Author, A.-B.: Contribution title. In: 9th International Proceedings
on Proceedings, pp. 1--2. Publisher, Location (2010)

\bibitem{ref_url1}
LNCS Homepage, \url{http://www.springer.com/lncs}. Last accessed 4
Oct 2017
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your document so we can find out how to do what you ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `\titlerunning` with an abbreviated title:

```
\title{Contribution Title Contribution Title Contribution Title
  Contribution Title Contribution Title Contribution Title
  Contribution Title Contribution Title Contribution Title
  Contribution Title Contribution Title\thanks{Supported by organization x.}}

\titlerunning{Contribution Title Abbreviated}
```

Comment: Thanks that did the track I took out the text so it's just blanked with a page number of the odd pages while even still will keep the authors.